# Changing a variable changes the previously assigned variable as well

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, binary-search-tree

I'm having what I'm sure is a basic logic error but I can't seem to fix it. I'm sorting a GenericSimpleArrayList before creating a tree using both the unsorted (postorder) and sorted (inorder) lists. When I sort one of the lists it sorts them both? I'm not sure why.

```
public static <AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>> BinaryNode<AnyType>constructBST ( GenericSimpleArrayList<AnyType> postorder ){


    GenericSimpleArrayList <AnyType> g = postorder;

    quicksort(postorder, new SortFunctor()); //this is where i sort the list.

    GenericSimpleArrayList <AnyType> inorder = postorder;
    return constructTree(inorder, g);

}
```

Can anyone help me fix this? Why does it sort both g and postorder when I only sort postorder? Thanks.

Edit: Added constructTree.

```
public static <AnyType> BinaryNode<AnyType> constructTree(GenericSimpleArrayList<AnyType> inorder, GenericSimpleArrayList<AnyType> postorder) {
    int nodes = postorder.size();

    AnyType root = postorder.get(nodes-1);
    BinaryNode<AnyType> left = null;
    BinaryNode<AnyType> right = null;

    if (nodes > 1) {
        int rootPos = 0;
        for (int loop = 0; loop <= nodes-1; loop++) {

            if (inorder.get(loop).equals(root)) {
                rootPos = loop;
                //System.out.println(loop);
            } else {
                //System.out.println("Not found at pos: " + loop);
            }
        }

        if (rootPos != 0) {
            GenericSimpleArrayList <AnyType> leftInorder = new GenericSimpleArrayList();//(AnyType) new Object[rootPos];
            GenericSimpleArrayList <AnyType> leftPostorder = new GenericSimpleArrayList();//(AnyType[]) new Object[rootPos];
            for (int loop = 0; loop < rootPos; loop++) {
                leftInorder.add(inorder.get(loop));
                leftPostorder.add(postorder.get(loop));
            }
            left = constructTree(leftInorder, leftPostorder );
        }

        if (rootPos < nodes-1){
            GenericSimpleArrayList <AnyType> rightInorder = new GenericSimpleArrayList();//(AnyType[]) new Object[nodes - rootPos - 1];
            GenericSimpleArrayList <AnyType> rightPostorder = new GenericSimpleArrayList();//(AnyType[]) new Object[rightInorder.length];
            for (int loop = 0; loop < nodes-rootPos-1; loop++){
                rightInorder.add(inorder.get(rootPos + loop + 1));
                rightPostorder.add(postorder.get(rootPos + loop));
            }

            right = constructTree(rightInorder, rightPostorder);
        }


    }

    return new BinaryNode<AnyType>(root, left, right);

}
```

Comment: Show us what `constructTree` does please

Comment: This is what we call "pass by reference". When you assign a vairable to  another. Then both of them has the same "reference". If you change inside of the reference, they would both show the same values of the reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does it sort both g and postorder when I only sort postorder?

```
GenericSimpleArrayList <AnyType> g = postorder;
```

`postorder` is a *reference* to an object.  When you copy this *reference* you now have two *references* to an object.  However there is still only one object.

I don't know the API to your custom ArrayList but I assume you can do

```
GenericSimpleArrayList<AnyType> g = new GenericSimpleArrayList<AnyType>(postorder);
```

or

```
GenericSimpleArrayList<AnyType> g = new GenericSimpleArrayList<AnyType>();
for(AnyType at: postorder)
    g.add(at);
```

Most likely your sorting utility sorts the collection in place.  This is very common for `sort` functions to alter the original list.

If you want to preserve both the original order and sort the list, I suggest first taking a copy of the list.

An alternetive is to use a different structures like a TreeMap to record the String in sorted order and the index of the original position.

Comment: Well, that's what I tried to do by creating `g`. How would I make a copy of the list?

Comment: @SarahvdByl I can only guess the API you are using but added some likely examples.

Answer (score 2):

```
GenericSimpleArrayList <AnyType> g = postorder;

GenericSimpleArrayList <AnyType> inorder = postorder;
```

In these two statements, all the three variable will be referring to the same reference hold by `postorder` initially. Because you are doing reference assignment and update in one object state will reflect into all the reference variable.

```
constructTree(inorder, g);
```

So when you make the above call then you are passing the same same reference.

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
GenericSimpleArrayList <AnyType> g = postorder;
```

you only define a new name `g` for the *same* object. If you want `g` to be a different List, you need to create it newly (that is really call the *constructor*) and copy `postorder`'s contents into it.